# Плавная отрисовка графика функции с помощью таймера

Tags: c++-cli

Есть метод `drawdifnet(wht,Nt)`
Он рисует вот это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но проблема в том что я хочу чтобы с помощью таймера он выводил каждую линию(как анимация)

Мои попытки решить свою проблему:

1)Если я сделаю таким образом

```
timer1->Enabled = true;
timer1->Tick += gcnew EventHandler(drawdifnet(wht,Nt));
timer1->Start();
timer1->Stop();
```

то ошибка

2)Добавил я свои параметры в событие,да оно компилируется но оно не строится по секундно.Я вот что имею ввиду(весь код метода `drawdifnet` закидываем в обработчик события `Tick`)

```
private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e,double** wht,int Nt)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < Nt - 1; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < Nt; i++)//Было Nx
            {
        chart2->Series["" + (j + 1).ToString()]->Points->AddXY(i, wht[j][i]);                   
        }
    }
```

После я уже запускаю таймер в главном методе(и всё равно ничего плавно и анимационно не строится)

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
    {
///---Остальные рабочие функции---///
    timer1->Enabled = true;
    timer1->Start();

}
```

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ!**
Перед всеми методами объявил

```
int ik, jk;
```

Изменённый Tick

```
private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e, double** wht, int Nt)
{       
    chart2->Series["" + (jk + 1).ToString()]->Points->AddXY(ik, wht[jk][ik]);
    ik++;
    if (ik == Nt)
    {
        ik = 1;
        jk++;
        if (jk == Nt - 1)
            timer1->Stop();
    }
    }
```

Вызов в `Button_Click`

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
    {
            ///Остальной Код

            ik = 1;
            jk = 1;
            timer1->Start();
    }
```

Но теперь совсем не рисует график.

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ-1-05-2017**

Поискав и почитав кучу примеров выяснилось следующее

Вот код(спасибо пользователю Alexander Petrov)

```
private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e,int Nt,double** wht)
    {
        chart2->Series["" + (jk + 1).ToString()]->Points->AddXY(ik, wht[jk][ik]);
        ik++;
        if (ik == Nt)
        {
            ik = 1;
            jk++;
            if (jk == Nt - 1)
                timer1->Stop();
        }
    }
```

переменные `jk,ik` у меня глобальные а вот `Nt,wht[j][i]` - нет, и когда я их добавляю как параметры

```
private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e,int Nt,double** wht)
```

то у меня высвечивается следующая ошибка на этой строке(в конструкторе формы)

```
this->timer1->Tick += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &TransEquForm::timer1_Tick);
```

Код ошибки C`3352:`
Указанная функция не соотвествует типу делегата

И в главной кнопке(где всё-всё) я и оставил эти строчки,так как судя по примерам в интернете при `timer-Enabled=true;` стартует событие `timer_Tick`

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
    {
            timer1->Interval = 2000;
            timer1->Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Добавьте задержку между отрисовками. И не нужно каждый раз выставлять толщину линий, вынесите этот код за пределы верхнего цикла ```for```. И у вас ошибка с границами в циклах.

Comment: Событие `Tick` отрабатывает в gui-потоке. Пока не отработает, чарт не прорисуется.

Comment: @UladzimirPalekh задержка между отрисовками это метод Sleep?

Comment: @beginner, да, ```Thread.Sleep()```

Comment: @UladzimirPalekh а с помощью timer1 возможно создать?

Если я правильно понял MSDN то Thread в С++ уже не поддерживается(сомневаюсь что они не смогли добавить простого кода)

Потому что при создании потока компилятор забил тревогу.

Comment: Если в `Tick` добавить строку `Text = ik + " " + jk;` выводятся номера в заголовке формы?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov нет не выводятся.

Comment: Значит или таймер, или кнопка не подписаны на событие.

Comment: Проблема решена?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov увы нет.
все говорят переходить на Си Шарп но по заданию не положено.
Перебираю варианты

Comment: Что именно не получается? [Посмотрите](http://ideone.com/GVkO0o), я сделал простой пример: на форме `Chart`, `Timer`, `Button`. Чарту задал у `Series` свойство `ChartType = Line`, остальное по умолчанию. Кликаем кнопку - плавно рисуется зигзаг, форма при этом не замерзает.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov таймер заработал,и с этим же кодом,спасибо

Сейчас я ищу различные способы как передать массив с координатами точек в событие таймера.
Но это уже наверное другой вопрос создам.

Comment: Да, всегда можно задать новый вопрос. А так, сделать массив полем формы. К полю можно обращаться из любого метода/события.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте переменные `i`, `j` полями формы.

Когда стартуете таймер в `button1_Click`, задайте им значения

```
i = 1;
j = 1;
timer1->Start();
```

И уберите строку `timer1->Enabled = true;` потому что это тоже запускает таймер.

В обработчике события `timer1_Tick` пишете:

```
chart2->Series["" + (j + 1).ToString()]->Points->AddXY(i, wht[j][i]);

i++;
if (i == Nt)
{
    i = 1;
    j++;
    if (j == Nt - 1)
        timer.Stop();
}
```

Это вместо циклов `for`.

---

Переходите на C# и на ваши вопросы будут сбегаться толпы народа, могущего ответить. Вам бы тут и асинхронный код предложили, и с `Task`ами...

Comment: К сожалению по заданию нужно на C++ поэтому и воюю с ним.
Снова не запускается но я уверен что это моя ошибка.

Поэтому вопрос

`i = 1;
j = 1;
timer1->Start();`

Эту часть кода я оставляю у себя в главном методе же?
Не в событии Tick?

Просто график не рисуется.

Comment: @beginner - это в баттон-клике должно быть.

Comment: да он у меня в баттон-клике, но не рисуется.
Обновлю сейчас код в своём сообщении