# Передача в coбытие timer1_Tick двумерного динамического массива

Tags: c++-cli

Продолжение этой темы но с другим вопросом

[Плавная отрисовка графика функции с помощью таймера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/658916/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0)

В программе есть главный двумерный динамический массив,который создаётся вот здесь

```
   private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
        {
    //---Поля для других методов;
            int Nx, Nt;//На сколько частей разбиваетсся отрезок сетки       
                Nx = Convert::ToInt32(textBox5->Text);
                Nt = Convert::ToInt32(textBox6->Text);

                //Создание динамического двумерного массива для сеточных преобразований
                double **wht = new double *[Nt];
                for (int i = 0; i < Nt; i++)
                    wht[i] = new double[Nx];
//вызовы методов,которые вычисляют и записывают значения в wht
    }
```

Вне `button1_Click` тоже есть методы,которые принимают этот массив как параметр,но всё работает отлично потому что эти все методы и функции вызываются опять же в `button1_Click`

А вот `timer1_Click` не принимает входные параметры
Стоит написать дополнительные параметры, компилятор сразу указывает на эту строку со следующей ошибкой

```
this->timer1->Tick += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &TransEquForm::timer1_Tick);

error C3352: void TransEqu::TransEquForm::timer1_Tick(System::Object ^,System::EventArgs ^,double **): указанная функция не соответствует типу делегата "void (System::Object ^,System::EventArgs ^)"
```

Были предприняты следующие действия

1)Сделать глобальной переменной,полем формы 
например простые переменные(не массивы) ещё возможно создать глобально,а вот чтобы массив с этим столкнулся впервые.

Ознакомился с этим вопросом [Глобальный динамический массив](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/268513/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2) и решил применить в своём проекте.

Итогом стало то,что при работе следующего кода

```
double** wht;

        double** created(int Nt,int Nx)
        {
            double **wht = new double *[Nt];
            for (int i = 0; i < Nt; i++)
                wht[i] = new double[Nx];
            return wht;
        }
```

При использовании массива `wht` происходят следующие исключения

```
Необработанное исключение типа "System.NullReferenceException" в TransEqu.exe
Дополнительные сведения: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.
```

Но тот вопросы идеально подходит для работы с консолью и при использовании в `WinForms` возникли вышеуказанные трудности

2)Заголовочные файлы,классы
Была попытка реализовать этот вариант но тоже возникают проблемы и опять с массивом.Дело в том что компоненты формы неохотно взаимодействуют,особенно если в заголовочный файл нужно получить какое-то значение.

**UPD**

Сформулирую вопрос
Как динамический массив(который создаётся в `button1_Click`) передать в событие `timer1_Tick`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сигнатуру обработчика события `Timer.Tick` изменить нельзя.

Сделайте `wht` полем формы. И везде используйте это поле.

```
public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
    // тут конструктор формы, объявления других компонентов

    // Поля
    private:
        int i, j;
        double** wht;

        void created(int Nt, int Nx)
        {
            // используется поле
            wht = new double *[Nt];

            // тут i - локальная переменная (имеется объявление int)
            for (int i = 0; i < Nt; i++)
                wht[i] = new double[Nx];
        }

    private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        // тут используем поля i, j, wht
    }
};
```

---

У вас написано:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    //---Поля для других методов;
    int Nx, Nt;
    ...
}
```

В данном случае, `Nx` и `Nt` **не** поля, а *локальные* переменные! Не нужно их путать!

*Поля* объявляются на уровне класса (в вашем случае формы) и доступны во *всех* методах (функциях) этого класса.

*Локальные переменные* объявляются на уровне метода и доступны *только* в этом методе.

Answer (score 1):

В Вашем примере с "глобальным" массивом есть небольшая ошибка, которая все портит.

```
double** wht;

        double** created(int Nt,int Nx)
        {
            double **wht = new double *[Nt];
            for (int i = 0; i < Nt; i++)
                wht[i] = new double[Nx];
            return wht;
        }
```

Внутри функции Вы еще раз объявляете переменную double **wht и этим экранируете внешнюю (глобальную) с тем же именем. И вдобавок получаете утечку памяти. Это и есть источник Ваших исключений, т.к. у Вас глобальный указатель остался не инициализированным, а Вы его пытаетесь использовать.
Исправьте внутри функции *created()* на:

```
wht = new double *[Nt];
```

и все должно заработать.

Comment: Да, и при использовании глобальной переменной (указателя) функция может уже не возвращать адрес массива, а можно вернуть, например, код ошибки.

Comment: Этот способ я использовал как один из вариантов но он и не подошёл,вы всё правильно расписали.

так как у меня функция,а мне нужно работать именно с массивом.