# Исключение в событии timer_Tick-Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

Продолжение этого вопроса(Спасибо Alexander Petrov за объяснение)

[Передача в coбытие timer1_Tick двумерного динамического массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/663788/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B2-co%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-timer1-tick-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0)

но на уже другую проблему
Глобальная переменная и метод.

```
double** wht;

void created(int Nt, int Nx)
             {
                 // используется поле
                 wht = new double *[Nt];
                 // тут i - локальная переменная (имеется объявление int)
                 for (int i = 0; i < Nt; i++)
                     wht[i] = new double[Nx];
             }
```

Последовательно методов до button1_Click()

```
 double** wht;

   public:void created(int Nt,int Nx)
   {
   //код;
   }

   public:void drawfunc(int T,double xmin,double xmax)
   {
    //код;
   }

   public:void calculatedifnet(double wht,double xmin,double hx,double ht, double a,int Nt,int Nx,int T)
   {
    //код;
   }

   public:void writeinto(double wht,int Nx,int Nt)
    {
    //код;
   }

   public:void drawdifnet(double wht,int Nt)
   {
    //код;
   }
   private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
        {
            int Nt = Convert::ToInt32(textBox6->Text);              
            chart1->Series["Series2"]->Points->AddXY(ik, wht[jk][ik]);//---Исключение
            ik++;
            if (ik == Nt)
            {
                ik = 1;
                jk++;
                if (jk == Nt)
                    timer1->Stop();
            }
        }
```

Тип исключения

```
   Необработанное исключение типа "System.NullReferenceException" в TransEqu.exe
    Дополнительные сведения: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.
```

А это уже последовательность методов внутри `button1_Click()`

```
 //Вызов функций
    created(Nt,Nx);
    drawfunc(T, xmin, xmax);
    calculatedifnet(wht, xmin, hx, ht, a, Nt, Nx, T);
    writeinto(wht, Nx, Nt);
    drawdifnet(wht, Nt);
```

Первые мысли:
Я подумал что возможно я не так выстраиваю последовательность и массив просто не инициализирован значениями.

Но как видно во многих методах,глобальный массив `wht` используется как параметр.

И в программе есть метод `writeinto(wht, Nx, Nt)`,который записывает результаты вычисления массива `wht[j][i]` в текстовый файл.

Следовательно, если есть сохранённые результаты в файлы(Я проверял по времени),значит программа работает с этим массивом. Это значит что проблемный участок кода находится в `timer_Tick`.

Было попробовать старый вариант,а именно цикл `for`(да вы можете сказать то,что цикл `for` лишний но перебирались все варианты,которые приходили в голову)

```
for (ik = 0; ik<= Nt - 1; ik++)
        {
            for (jk = 0; jk<= Nt - 1; jk++)
            {
                chart1->Series["Series2"]->Points->AddXY(ik, wht[jk][ik]);
            }
        }
```

Но результат такой же..

Если отталкиваться от работы массива и метода `created()` то функция работает нормально,массив создаётся и вычисляется.

Точка остановки вот что показала и на этой строке и до неё[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Неопределённое значение,да массив динамический,навеяло сомнения но..
Но я смотрю на работу остальных методов и вижу что они всё считают.

**UPD** 11-05-2017

Я забыл главное и простое правило, что при совпадении имени локальной переменной с глобальной,локальная берёт вверх

В итоге я изменил параметры и локальные переменные в своём коде.
Например так:

```
 public:void calculatedifnet(double whkt,double xmin,double hx,double ht,double a,int Nt,int Nx,int T)
       {
        //код;
       }
```

Вызов метода в button1_Click оставил без изменений:

```
calculatedifnet(wht, xmin, hx, ht, a, Nt, Nx, T)
```

Ничего не изменилось..

Comment: Запуск таймера и первое выполнение `timer1_Tick` точно происходит после `created`?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов да,я уверен потому что и по шаговая отладка это отчасти показала.
Дело в том,что функции указанные выше идут первее чем запуск таймера,а они в свою очередь уже работают после created.

Comment: Не видя весь код в целом, нельзя сказать, где именно ошибка. Проходите в отладчике, ищите, где присваивается неверное значение. Обращу внимание, что во многих методах используется параметр `wht`, аналогичный по названию полю `wht`. Для начала я бы сделал переименование, чтобы было проще их различать.